# Obtain Audio Attributes to All Spotify Songs By Artist

Tags: r, api, spotify, httr, libspotify

This is a follow-up question to: [Accessing Spotify API for Multiple Artists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074526/accessing-spotify-api-for-multiple-artists-in-r/40074876#40074876)

My goal here is to extract multiple artists from Spotify's API and then retrieve all of the songs by artist with their attributes.

So this is what we have done so far as a result to the previous question:

Retrieve info about the artist (not by song):

```
artistName = 'ytcracker'

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', mytoken)

URI = paste0('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=', artistName,'&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist')
response2 = GET(url = URI, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
Artist = content(response2)
Artist
```

Multiple Artists if you know artist ID from the code above.

```
URI = paste0('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists?ids=', Artist$artists$items[[2]]$id,",", '1Mxqyy3pSjf8kZZL4QVxS0')
response2 = GET(url = URI, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
Artists = content(response2)
```

How do I extract multiple artists songs with their attributes?

This is the link for audio-features:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-audio-features/

This is my attempt:

```
artistID = '1Mxqyy3pSjf8kZZL4QVxS0'
HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', mytoken)
URI = paste0('https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features', artistID)
response2 = GET(url = URI, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
Artist = content(response2)
Artist
```

Response:

```
raw(0)
```

https://github.com/rweyant/spotifyr

This is a good reference but I can't set my credentials even after opening the 'httr' library.

```
set_credentials(client_id=CLIENTID,client_secret=CLIENTSECRET)
```

Error: could not find function "set_credentials"

Any help is great, thanks!

Revised with beginning section with API credentials:

```
clientID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

response = POST(
  'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(clientID, secret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
 )

 mytoken = content(response)$access_token
```

Comment: @Hack-R if you think of anything because I know you were able to solve the previous question. Thanks!

Comment: It probably means the library was not installed and loaded correctly, I tested this and dependencies are not being installed recursively.  In a fresh R session,  this should work `install.packages(c('httr','jsonlite','RSelenium','RCurl','XML','stringr','stringi','plyr'),dep=TRUE);
devtools::install_github('rweyant/spotifyr')`

Comment: This is the error that comes up when I do this: Error in assign("client_redirect_uri", client_redirect_uri, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  argument "client_redirect_uri" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getFeatures<-function(spotify_ID,token){
  req <- httr::GET(paste0("https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/",spotify_ID), add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
  json1<-httr::content(req)
  dados=data.frame(id=json1$id,
                   danceability=json1$danceability,
                   energy=json1$energy,
                   key=json1$key,
                   loudness=json1$loudness,
                   mode=json1$mode,
                   speechiness=json1$speechiness,
                   acousticness=json1$acousticness,
                   instrumentalness=json1$instrumentalness,
                   liveness=json1$liveness,
                   valence=json1$valence,
                   tempo=json1$tempo,
                   duration_ms=json1$duration_ms,
                   time_signature=json1$time_signature,
                   uri=json1$uri,
                   analysis_url=json1$analysis_url,stringsAsFactors = F)
  return(dados)
}

KanyeFatherStretch <- getFeatures("4KW1lqgSr8TKrvBII0Brf8")

Try this if it helps
```

Comment: could you provide a sample token, it could be a random number but how would I apply that to this? I get an error saying: "Error in token$sign : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: Also when I apply it the way you have it, it states: Error in structure(list(method = method, url = url, headers = keep_last(headers),  : 
  argument "token" is missing, with no default

Comment: httr::config(token = token) change this with your Oauth Authorization Code please...This Token here refers to the o-auth token you get post authenticating with the Spotify API.

Comment: thanks, I just edited the question to have a sample of what I have in my original dataset. If I run everything after "Revised with beginning section with API credentials:" and then your script with my API credentials it doesn't work. Would you be able to revise your answer so that it meets that. I am very new to this, which is why I am asking for this. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Replace with  add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue)  Instead of httr::config(token = token) in the above code please

Comment: Also  refresh your Tokens

Comment: Your Welcome Nick :-)

Comment: I added a follow-up question to your answer which goes alittle more in depth. If you have any thoughts, please let me know. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958438/audio-features-for-spotify-tracks-on-an-artists-album

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with HTTP requests in R, but if the following line relies on string concatenation...

```
URI = paste0('https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features', artistID)
```

you'll need a trailing backslash on the first argument so that the second parameter properly joins the URI.

Additionally though, [the Audio Features endpoint takes a Spotify ID for a *track*, rather than an artist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-audio-features/). What I would recommend you do is to grab the top 10 or so tracks for the artist you're interested in, and use the [Get Several Audio Features](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-audio-features/) endpoint to get the audio features for all of the tracks. That should give you a pretty good representation of the sound of an artist. You could take an average of the features if you need a smaller representation, but be aware that averaging will likely reduce the accuracy of the data.

Comment: I tried doing this in the original question and it gave me an output of "raw(0)". Do you know how to do it on a track level. Still having trouble getting the audio attributes. Thanks for the feeback.